# Create a new kind of site Alfresco 5.2

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm trying to create a new type of site. When I'm creating a new one, only appears 1 type in the select: "Collaboration Site". I wish to add more options. For example "Custom Site", and for that site having predefined pages and dashboard. I've got a solution for this but it's modifying presets.xml and share-header.get.js files. I want to do the same by adding my own files, not editing existent files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct to want to avoid touching out-of-the-box files that came with your Alfresco distribution. You can add new site presets through the standard extension mechanisms.

For example, you should be able to put a presets.xml file in web-extension/site-data/presets that describes your presets. It sounds like you already have an example of what that should look like.

Then, under web-extension/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/modules you can add create-site.get.js which has something like:

```
var sitePresets = [
   {id: "site-dashboard", name: msg.get("title.collaborationSite")},
   {id: "some-new-preset", name: msg.get("title.somePreset")}
];
model.sitePresets = sitePresets;
```

Note that this has changed slightly depending on which version of Alfresco you are using. For example, in 5.2, I don't believe you need to override create-site.get.js as shown above. Instead, you can use a Share extension module. Create a file called presets.xml in web-extension/site-data/extensions:

```
<extensions>
  <modules>
    <module>
      <id>Additional Site Presets</id>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
      <evaluator type="default.extensibility.evaluator"/>
      <customizations>
        <customization>
           <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco</targetPackageRoot>
           <sourcePackageRoot>com.someco.presets</sourcePackageRoot>
        </customization>

        <customization>
           <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco.share.pages</targetPackageRoot>
           <sourcePackageRoot>com.someco.presets</sourcePackageRoot>
           <alwaysApply>
              <webscript>share-header</webscript>
           </alwaysApply>
        </customization>
      </customizations>
    </module>
  </modules>
</extension>
```

With that extension in place you also have to override share-header.get.js. To do that, create a file with that name under web-extension/site-webscripts/com/someco/presets/share/header with this content:

```
var siteService = widgetUtils.findObject(model.jsonModel, "id", "SITE_SERVICE");
if (siteService && siteService.config)
{
   siteService.config.additionalSitePresets = [
      { value: "some-site-preset", label: msg.get("title.someSite") }
   ];
}
```

This should add the new "some-site-preset" to the list you see when you create a new site in 5.2.

Comment: It didn't work for me, at least with Alfresco 5.2.f.

Comment: Updated my answer with specifics related to 5.2.